# How to install Spring ROO gvNix addon?

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

After following the instructions (code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/InstallGvnix) for installing gvNIX, I keep getting the following:

```
web roo> addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.gvnix.cit.security.roo.addon 
Could not find specified bundle with symbolic name: org.gvnix.cit.security.roo.addon
```

I think this is a problem with RooBot?

If I try the instructions again, using the URL, I get the following:

```
web roo> osgi start --url http://gvnix.googlecode.com/svn/repo/org/gvnix/org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon/1.2.1-RELEASE/org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon-1.2.1-RELEASE.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle  org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon [83]: Unable to resolve 83.0: missing requirement [83.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.gvnix.web.i18n.roo.addon)(version>=1.2.0)(!(version>=‌​2.0.0)))
```

How can I install gvNix?

Answer (score 2):

We are working on improve gvNIX doc, whereas it is recommended to download and install gvNIX 1.2.1, that includes Spring Roo 1.2.4 and all gvNIX addons.

Comment: Note current gvNIX version is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Some add-ons requires another add-ons to work: `org.gvnix.web.screen.roo.addon` requires `org.gvnix.web.i18n.roo.addon`.

Try to install the required add-on before.